# Is this expression an xvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, decltype, xvalue

The C++ standard says the following about 'xvalues' (N4762 § 7.2.1.4):

> An expression is an xvalue if it is:
>    -   . . .
>    -   a class member access expression designating a non-static data member of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue

Consider the following code fragment (using Boost to print the type of an expression):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

struct X {
    int var;
} x;

int main()
{
    auto extended_type = type_id_with_cvr<decltype( std::move(x).var )>();
    std::cout << extended_type.pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

My question is about the expression `std::move(x).var`:

Based on the text in the standard, I expect the expression to be an xvalue, but the output is `int`, not `int &&`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is about the expression: `std::move(x).var`
>
> Based on the text in the standard, I expect the expression to be an xvalue,

It is.

> but the output is `int`, not `int &&`

That's because `decltype` comes in two forms. It can give information on how a name is declared, or it can either give information on the type and category of the expression.

Since `std::move(x).var` is a member access, you get the former. To get the latter, use `decltype((std::move(x).var))` (with double parentheses).

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Glad I wasn't wrong about the expression type

Comment: So this is an actual use case for `decltype` with *double parentheses*!